# NGINX Reverse Proxying & Static Files

Tags: nginx, server, reverse-proxy

I would like to reverse proxy my NodeJS backend through NGINX, but I keep getting the 403 Forbidden Error, logged by NGINX as

```
[error] 10#10: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, 
client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
host: "localhost:8888
```

My configuration for the server block:

```
server {

  charset utf8;
  listen 80 default_server;

  location / {
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:5000;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
  }

  location /assets/ {
      expires 30d;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
      root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
      try_files $uri =404;
  }
}
```

After doing some research, it seems like it may be related to [NGINX identifying `/` as a query for a directory listing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/) and would most likely require me to add `index index.html` to solve the issue (it didn't). My configuration also matches [that presented by the official NGINX configurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/) for reverse proxies.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers :)

Comment: I don't understand the `localhost:8888` part of the error message. You should also test your configuration using `nginx -T`

Comment: The localhost:8888 is the host from which I am calling the request. I don't believe it has anything to do with it, but my setup runs in docker (see this [docker-compose file](https://github.com/futureboyHQ/website/blob/feature/6/docker/docker-compose.yml)). Also albeit it doesn't give much more info, you can find the `nginx -T` printout [here](https://pastebin.com/HHAk1Kba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using server `localhost` which is the other `server` block.

The `server` block in your question is the default server, but the other one has an explicit `server_name localhost` statement, which takes precedence.

You should probably remove the other server block, so that there is only one server block, which will always be used.

The problem file is located at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

Selection of `server` block is explained in [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Comment: Great! This definitely solved my issue! I applied your solution by adding a `RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` command to an nginx dockerfile. Cheers :D